# gStreamerを使ってWebカメラのRTSP配信を行う際、挙動がおかしい

Tags: c++, gnome

現在、gStreamerを使用してWebカメラの映像をRTSPで共有しようとしています。
現状、RTSPを使ってビデオを共有することはできていますが、映像の品質が悪く、また映像内で何かが動くと映像に大きな乱れが生じてしまいます。

RTSPを使わずにカメラ映像をそのまま表示すると、画質も良く、動作もスムーズなので、おそらくサーバー側の問題だと思います。

何か考えられる原因があれば教えていただきたいです。

サーバー側のパイプライン
`(ksvideosrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0)`

クライアント側のパイプライン
`(rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test protocols="tcp" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink)`

以下に現状の動画をアップしました。

RTSPなしでの表示`(ksvideosrc ! decodebin ! autovideosink)`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzxgnwivzRaO-J9AxaU4IM_xh6XAlmTk/view?usp=sharing
RTSPでの配信
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3CCHyC4qqKin1j25CqGmo0MKq2FHi2P/view?usp=sharing